# Finding value of radius in inscribed circle relationships

Tags: analytic-geometry

I got this question on a grade 11 multiple choice test and had no idea how to solve it.

Q: In the diagram, the circle with centre X is tangent to the largest circle and passes through the centre of the largest circle. The circles with centres Y and Z are each tangent to the other three circles, as shown. The circle with centre X has radius 1. The circles with centres Y and Z each have radius *r*. The value of *r* is? Note: the diagram isn't to scale.
[image: My replication of the diagram given. The diagram given wasn't to scale and this isn't either.]

Comment: One of the things about multiple-choice is you only have to check the answer. In this case you can draw the figure in the answer, label the side $CY$ with the answer, and see if it "fits". For all but one of the answers, you'll find a contradiction somewhere, such as the three sides of a right triangle don't satisfy the Pythagorean theorem. One answer will make everything correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 3 circles inscribed in a larger circle]

First, as shown in the diagram above, draw a horizontal line through $X$. By symmetry, it will go from the tangent point on the left and also through the tangent point of the circles $Y$ and $Z$. Since this horizontal line is perpendicular to the circle's tangent line on the left side, and the line from the larger circle's center to that point is also perpendicular to that same line, this means these $2$ lines overlap. As the largest circle's center is on circle $X$, it must be on its right side. Call this point $O$. Since the radius of the circle $X$ is $1$, and the radius of the outside circle is the diameter of $X$, this means it's $2$.

Draw a line from $O$ through $Y$ to the edge of the outside circle and call the point where it first crosses the $Y$ circle $A$ and where it touches the outside circle $B$. The length of $OB$ is $2$ and the length of $YB$ is $r$ so

$$|OY| = 2 - r \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Draw a line from $Y$ to where it meets the drawn horizontal line, and call the point where it meets $C$. Note it's at a right angle to the horizontal line. Also, since it's on the circumference of circle $Y$, you have

$$|CY| = r \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, draw a line joining $X$ and $Y$. As it goes through the circles' $X$ and $Y$ tangent point, its length is $1 + r$. Now, $\triangle XYC$ is a right-angled triangle, so by the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
|XC|^2 + r^2 & = (r+1)^2 \\
|XC|^2 & = (r+1)^2 - r^2 \\
|XC| & = \sqrt{(r+1)^2 - r^2} \\
& = \sqrt{2r + 1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $|XO| = 1$, you have

$$|OC| = |XC| - |XO| = \sqrt{2r + 1} - 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Since $\triangle OYC$ is a right-angled triangle, you can use the Pythagorean theorem again to relate the lengths of the $3$ sides using the values in \eqref{eq1A}, \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq4A} as

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
r^2 + (\sqrt{2r + 1} - 1)^2 & = (2 - r)^2 \\
r^2 + (2r + 1 - 2\sqrt{2r + 1} + 1) & = r^2 - 4r + 4 \\
2r + 2 - 2\sqrt{2r + 1} & = - 4r + 4 \\
- 2\sqrt{2r + 1} & = -6r + 2 \\
\sqrt{2r + 1} & = 3r - 1 \\
2r + 1 & = 9r^2 - 6r + 1 \\
0 & = 9r^2 - 8r \\
0 & = r(9r - 8)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Since $r \gt 0$, this means that

$$9r - 8 = 0 \implies r = \frac{8}{9} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and detailed answer. It clears it up.